# BDE installer for Delphi 12

Tags: delphi, bde

I have a package in `Delphi 11` that uses `BDE`. Now I'm trying `Delphi 12` but I can't find the `BDE installer` for this edition.

Does anybody knows where I can find it ?

Comment: Look in the Embarcadero download section after you logged in.

Comment: I'm logged in but I can't see "download" section

Comment: check https://my.embarcadero.com/

Comment: It was not found there either

Comment: I can find it in [my.embarcadero.com/#downloadsPage](https://my.embarcadero.com/#downloadsPage) as 5th entry in the list.

Comment: Just curios, does BDE still work? I thought it was depreciated around ten or fifteen years ago. We have an app that uses it that still works for the most part but we are rewriting it from scratch because it was written Delphi 4 and had errors when we opened it in Delphi 10.4.

Comment: Yes, it works like a charm with Delphi 11 and I want the installer for Delphi 12

Comment: Well - well - well. Is it supported? Still updated? I must be ahead of the times. Is it a good solution? What about all the warnings in Delphi's IDE that say it's depreciated?

Comment: No, it isn't supported many years ago but... works fine until D11 and my Paradox databases needs it. Beside this, I prefer this type of database because my applications can run in multiuser mode with server acting just as file server. I don't know other free database engine that works with a file server. So I'm stack with BDE.

Comment: Well, then, have you checked out [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org)? I realize this is a client/server, however my two cents is that it is faster and much easier to set up than a file type database. Good luck programing!

Comment: I recently used the BDE installer that came with Delphi 12 and it didn't come with all the DLLs that my Delphi 6 or 7 has. Moreover, the new BDE install became the default, breaking existing environment that used to work. Saw a post someone saying just copy everything from existing D6/D7 BDE install folder over to the new D11/D12 BDE install folder (with all the extra sql dlls etc...). This solved it. I am too going to be migrating from BDE to FireDAC imminently...going to be fun :)

Comment: Some years ago I ripped out BDE/Paradox and used FireDAC and SQLite. It was an immediate success and no-one looked back. You're most certainly not stuck with Paradox. I remember it getting corrupted all the time, I don't know how you can say it's good :) Credit to BDE though: amazingly, it runs happily against SQL Server on Windows 10 and will probably continue work if not touched.

Comment: The reason I want BDE is that there is no need to have any `RDBMS` installed on the server (where the user may only have rights to store files, not applications) but to run locally with the ability for the user to select local or server-stored files in single and/or multi-user environment. In other words, I want the server to function only as a file server. My app is simple and works fine in a multi-user environment with BDE.

Comment: Another local database version that I use in my other applets is `Absolute Database` which is very good and free for single user but needs payment for multiple users. So for multiple users, `BDE` is a one-way street